# Disable master control from content page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I tried:

```
Master.FindControl("dropdownlist2").disabled=true
```

but it is not working, and I don't want to use `visible=true/false`.

How should I deal with it?

Thanks very much for advice!

Comment: is `dropdownlist2` id of something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such property as `disabled`.

Use `enabled` property and make it `false` so that the meaning does not get changed and the program would run as you want.

Do it like this:

```
Master.FindControl("dropdownlist2").Enabled = false
```

Comment: i added  Dim control2 As WebControl = Master.FindControl("dropdownlist2") before your line, and control2.Enabled = True  and it looks fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah! That seems that there was error in your code not mentioned here. But I am glad that I could be of some help! :)